# How to restrict input[type="text"] to a single line? It keeps breaking into multiple lines

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, textbox

I don't know why it is happening, but the inputs of text types have been breaking up into multiple lines for some reason. The search types and email types don't break lines; it's just the text type. I'm using Google Chrome 38 on Mac OS X so maybe that has something to do with it?

Here is the text type:
[image]

Here is the email type:
[image]

Here is the search type (don't mind the icon):
[image]

Here's the code:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="user_login_<?php echo $template->get_option( 'instance' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Username or Email', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="log" id="user_login_<?php echo $template->get_option( 'instance' ); ?>" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'log' ); ?>" />
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </label>
</p>

<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="user_pass_<?php echo $template->get_option( 'instance' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass_<?php echo $template->get_option( 'instance' ); ?>" class="input-text" />
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
    </label>
</p>
```

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure it is `<input type="text" />` and not `<textarea>`?

Comment: @JonathanCrowe yes I am a hundred percent sure. It's type="text", which is weird. I searched for this problem, but it's usually people trying to actually implement this rather than avoid this.

Comment: You better to show your html code for us better to help you.

Comment: @Edrich Added HTML code. Thanks again.

Comment: You have not added HTML code. You have added PHP code from which a server generates HTML code. HTML code is what browsers get, so please post a sample of that.

Comment: You also need to post the relevant CSS code; the problem is most probably there. Please try to reduce it to the minimum needed to actually reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when your input has the CSS rule:

```
word-break: break-word;
```

Just apply the following css and it should work:

```
.input-text {
    word-break:normal!important;
}
```